# Identity of moment-generating functions

Tags: distributions, moments, moment-generating-function

Are there any non-identical distributions which happen to have the same moment-generating function?

Comment: See Wikipedia under [Moment-generating function#Important properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Important_properties)

Comment: @onestop that answers it! if you want to put that as an answer I'll accep tit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

In an exercise, Stuart & Ord (*Kendall's Advanced Theory of Statistics*, 5th Ed., Ex. 3.12) quote a 1918 result of TJ Stieltjes (which apparently appears in his *[Oeuvres Completes](http://archive.org/details/oeuvrescompltesd02stie),*):

> If $f$ is an odd function of period $\frac{1}{2}$, show that
>
> $$\int_0^\infty x^r x^{-\log x} f(\log x) dx = 0$$
>
> for all integral values of $r$.  Hence show that the distributions
>
> $$dF = x^{-\log x}(1 - \lambda \sin(4\pi \log x))\ dx, \quad 0 \le x \lt \infty;\quad 0 \le |\lambda| \le 1,$$
>
> have the same moments whatever the value of $\lambda$.

(In the original, $|\lambda|$ appears only as $\lambda$; the restriction on the size of $\lambda$ arises from the requirement to keep all values of the density function $dF$ non-negative.)  The exercise is easy to solve via the substitution $x = \exp(y)$ and completing the square.  The case $\lambda=0$ is the well-known [lognormal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).

[image]

*The blue curve corresponds to $\lambda=0$, a lognormal distribution.  For the red curve, $\lambda = -1/4$ and for the gold curve, $\lambda = 1/2$.*

Comment: But the [lognormal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lognormal_distribution) does not have a moment-generating function.

Comment: That's an excellent point, onestop, and I have to agree with it.  I took the question in the sense of "having the same set of moments" and I should have pointed out that change of interpretation.  When the mgf exists *as a function* (and not just as a formal power series) then it can be inverted to produce a unique density to which it corresponds.

Comment: Its not true that the lognormal dont have mgf, its only that its not defined on an *open* interval containing zero

Comment: .....  see http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11009-014-9430-7

Comment: For the record, both @onestop and I were implicitly discussing the existence of an mgf *in a neighborhood of $0.$*  This sense is often assumed because one of the most basic uses of an mgf is to expand its MacLaurin series (Taylor series around $0$) to compute or analyze the moments and this requires the function to be defined in a neighborhood, not just at $0.$

Comment: @whuber: That's OK, but it seems to be understood implicitely so often that one forgets that mgf's can be useful otherwise too. See also (the links in) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/389846/moment-generating-function-for-lognormal-random-variable/390185#390185

Comment: Should *for all integral values of $r$* be *for all integer values of $r$*? If not, what does *integral* mean in this context?

Comment: @Richard "integer values" is poor grammar; "integral values" means "values that are integers."

Comment: @whuber, thank you. This was beyond my knowledge of English (not a native speaker).

Comment: I don't get this at all. The moment generating function is just the Laplace transform of the pdf, and it is a well-known and basic theorem that the Laplace transform of *any* two functions will be different unless their difference is some function which is zero almost everywhere. How can this result be true then?

Comment: One thought is that the original post is about the *moment-generating function* being unique, not the moments. The moments are just the derivatives of the moment-generating function, so if this function is analytic, then the moments totally characterize the moment-generating function as the coefficients of the Taylor expansion and are also unique. Is the idea here that this result (non-unique moments) can thus only happen if the function is *not* complex analytic, and thus some of the derivatives (and thus moments) don't exist?

Comment: @Mike The mgf needn't exist at all (in the sense of a function defined in a neighborhood of $0$).  Consider a [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution), for instance: its tail is heavier than exponential.  When the mgf does exist, the focus is not on being Complex analytic but on being Real analytic at the origin only.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. So if the mgf exists, it must be unique. However, because it's only real-analytic and not complex-analytic, we can have two different mgf's with the same derivatives at the origin. For instance, we could have two piecewise-analytic mgfs which agree on a neighborhood of 0 but then diverge beyond that, and which would thus have the same moments. If I get what you are saying correctly, that is.