# Random variable with finite logarithmic first moment, infinite logarithmic variance

Tags: variance, mean, random-variable, logarithm, moments

Could you provide an example of a random variable $X$ such that $|\mathbb{E}(\ln(X))|<\infty$ but $\text{Var}(\ln(X))=\infty$, if such a random variable exists at all?

<sub>Related: ["Random variable with finite exponential first moment, infinite exponential variance"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/512291)</sub>
<sub>Motivated by ["Is (covariance) stationarity preserved under log or exponential transformation?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/512205)</sub>.

Comment: Let $Y$ be a positive variable with finite expectation and infinite variance, then set $X=\exp(Y).$

Comment: Richard, you should perhaps include the condition that $Var(X)\leq \infty$.

Comment: Sorry it should strict inequality above.