Zero covariance of powers of random variables and independence
I have random variables $X,Y$ with support $(-\infty,\infty)$ and $\mathbf{E}[X]= \mathbf{E}[Y]=0$.
If $\mathbf{Cov}[X^i,Y^j]=0$ for all $ i,j=1,2,3,\ldots$, can one conclude that $X$ and $Y$ are independent by expressing all other non-linear relationships as Taylor series expansions.

The first half of the question--that of independence--is interesting, but the answer to the follow-on--"... as Taylor series expansions"--definitely is in the negative, because those expansions won't converge for arbitrary random variables and might even have zero radii of convergence.  // Where you indicate "support $[-\infty,\infty],$" (a) what does it mean to include the endpoints and (b) do you mean the support is the set of all real numbers or just it is a subset of real numbers?

BTW, this looks closely related to the question of whether the moments determine the distribution of a bivariate variable.  That is addressed for univariate variables at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25010.

Thanks for the comments @whuber. The square brackets is a typo which I have corrected.
